# Como evitar quebras de linhas excessivas num textarea

Tags: php, html

Então galera, como posso substituir num texto, quebras de linhas excessivas, fazendo que quando tenha **mais de uma quebra de linha seguida** essas ocorrências sejam substituídas por uma só, independente de quantas foram colocadas. Por exemplo:

O texto digitado pelo usuário:

```
<textarea>
    Paragráfo de texto
    <br />
    <br />
    Paragráfo de texto
    <br />
    Paragráfo de texto
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Paragráfo de texto
</textarea>
```

O texto que deve ser apresentado:

```
<textarea>
    Paragráfo de texto
    <br />
    Paragráfo de texto
    <br />
    Paragráfo de texto
    <br />
    Paragráfo de texto
</textarea>
```

Preciso disso no php :)

Comment: Veja se este link do SO ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize isto:

```
$html = "Seu conteúdo <br/><br/> quebras e mais quebras";
preg_replace("/(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/", "<br/>", $html);
```

Retirado de: [How to convert multiple br tag to a single br tag in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php)

Comment: Ajudou bastante Kenny! Vlw :)

Comment: As ordens chefe! ;)

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta está vaga, mas isso pode resolver:

```
preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string_recebida_do_textarea);
```

Exemplo de como funciona:

```
//Simulando uma string com várias quebras de linha
$str = '
a


b





c
';

// Aqui o resultado sanitizado
// A tag <pre> é desnecessária. Foi colocada para que possa ver pelo browser como se fosse plain/text 
echo '<pre>'.preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $str).'</pre>';
```

Comment: não funcionou para mim :(

Comment: É complicado entender com uma explicação vaga e um feedback mais vago ainda.

Comment: putz cara, tudo bem. Vou tentar melhorar um pouco para você entender melhor, apesar de não concordar com a sua definição de vago.

Comment: Daniel, o meu comentário posso até concordar que possa estar vago, mas a pergunta não é para tanto. Acho que a maneira como você aborda isso é incorreta. Isso é uma opinião minha. Acredito que ao invés de você dizer que "está vago" você poderia ter feito as perguntas que fez no comentário anterior. E falo isso nem por mim, mas por usuários novos. Imagina você abordando um usuário novo aqui no SO desse jeito? Talvez o cara nem volte mais. Mas enfim, é minha opinião e só. E sim, eu entendo o que o preg_replace faz no exemplo que você mandou, mas no meu caso tem uma particularidade que descobri

Comment: Os resultados estão sendo salvos no banco, e me pareceu que houve alguma modificação que me causou estranheza. AS quebras de linha estavam vindo com um <br />, seguido de um \n que foi o momento em que consegui substituir. Vou vendo aqui e depois falo como ficou. Obrigado por tentar ajudar